# get end dates from list of start dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query that brings back a list of references (products) that were at a specific status and an effective date.  Unfortunately when one product moves to a different status the system doesn't put an end date in, so I am wanting to generate the end date, based on the effective date and sequence number.  Is this possible?

```
Product  Status  EffectiveDate          Enddate SeqNo
10      *UC     2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 NULL    8590
584     UC      2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 NULL    8380
584     APA     2017-07-07 00:00:00.000 NULL    8620
584     APA3    2017-08-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    8630
902     *UC     2017-10-13 00:00:00.000 NULL    8590
902     APA     2017-10-13 00:00:00.000 NULL    8620
1017    *UC     2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 NULL    8590
1017    APA     2017-10-10 00:00:00.000 NULL    8620
```

SO I would want to return the following...

```
Product  Status  EffectiveDate          EndDate                     SeqNo
10      *UC     2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 NULL                        8590
584     UC      2017-02-28 00:00:00.000 2017-07-07 00:00:00.000     8380
584     APA     2017-07-07 00:00:00.000 2017-08-10 00:00:00.000     8620
584     APA3    2017-08-10 00:00:00.000 NULL                        8630
902     *UC     2017-10-13 00:00:00.000 2017-10-13 00:00:00.000     8590
902     APA     2017-10-13 00:00:00.000 NULL                        8620
1017    *UC     2017-09-01 00:00:00.000 2017-10-10 00:00:00.000     8590
1017    APA     2017-10-10 00:00:00.000 NULL                        8620
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lead()` :

```
select t.*, lead(EffectiveDate) over (partition by product order by SeqNo) as EndDate
from table t;
```

However, `lead()` starts from version `2012 +`, so you can use `apply` instead :

```
select t.*, t1.EffectiveDate as EndDate
from table t outer apply
     (select top (1) t1.*
      from table t1
      where t1.product = t.product and t1.SeqNo > t.SeqNo
      order by t1.SeqNo 
     ) t1;
```

Comment: I'm on SQL 2008 unfortunately so cannot use LEAD but the APPLY statement worked, thank you.